# Changing basis D-module homomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let D be a PID, V and W free D-modules of rank 4 and 5, respectively.  Suppose $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ is a D-module homomorphism, and $\mathbf{B}=\{v_1,...v_4\}$ is an ordered basis for $V$ and $\mathbf{B'}=\{w_1,...w_5\}$ is an ordered basis for $W$.
How does the matrix $A$ change if we change the basis $B'$ by replacing $w_1$ by $w_1+aw_2$ for some $a\in D$? Here $A\in D^{5\times 4}$ is such that left multiplication by $A$ on $D^4$ represents $\phi:V\rightarrow W$ with respect to $B$ and $B'$.
Attempt at solution:
$\phi(v_1)=a_{11}(w_1+aw_2)+a_{21}w_2+\cdots +a_{51}w_5=a_{11}w_1+(a_{11}a+a_{21})w_2+\cdots +a_{51}w_5$. Similarly for the other columns.  So, if $\alpha_1$ is row 1 of $A$ and $\alpha_2$ is row 2 of $A$, then $\alpha_2$ gets replaced by $a\alpha_1+\alpha_2$.
Where am I wrong, and what would be a correct solution? Thanks.

Comment: Now that I think about this, it might be that $\alpha_2$ gets replaced by $\alpha_2-a\alpha_1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\phi(v_1)=c_{11}w_1+\cdots +c_{51}w_5$. Consider $\phi(v_1)=d_{11}(w_1+aw_2)+d_{21}w_2+\cdots +c_{51}w_5=d_{11}w_1+(d_{11}a+d_{21})w_2+\cdots$.
$c_{11}=d_{11}$. $d_{11}a+d_{21}=c_{21}$. So, $d_{21}=c_{21}-ac_{11}$. Continue similarly. So, $\alpha_2$ gets replaced by $\alpha_2-a\alpha_1$.